# SweetAlert não cancela deleção

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, sweetalert

Criei um sistema de deleção com o sweetalert, ao clicar em deletar, ele não cancela a deleção. A linguagem utilizada é o PHP sem OO e PDO. Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue o codigo do alert e do botão:

```js
<script>
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.bt').click(function(){
    var th = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    Swal.fire({
     title: 'Are you sure?',
     text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
     type: 'warning',
     showCancelButton: true,
     confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
     cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
     confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
     $.ajax({
      url: 'phpAction/delete.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {idd:id},
      success: function(data){
       th.parents('tr').hide();
      }
     })
     if (result.value) {
      Swal.fire(
       'Deleted!',
       'Your file has been deleted.',
       'success'
       )
     }
    });

    
   });
  });

 </script>
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger bt" id="<?php echo $dados['idUsuario']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
```

Comment: Tentou usar o preconfirm?

Comment: Fiz um exemplo pra você dá uma olhada: [Olha ai](http://abre.ai/47W)

Comment: Mas como que eu faria para colocar essa função em um botão e selecionar o ID do banco de dados?

Comment: pode usar o data-id="" no botao ou url

Comment: Consegui solucionar, era só mudar $.ajax para depois do IF.